# Flutter - How do I store and display a text to a user based on date

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, I really need help on how to display the text to a user based on his selection. (say when the user clicks on 2020/12/21, The app should fetch data related to that date and displays it to the user)

Comment: your question is totally unclear.

Comment: @GTG in my opinion what you need is datepicker and some logic after a user pick a date in a datepicker. Where are you fetching data from ? Locally in the phone or remotely in a backend ?

Comment: @dm_tr I want the data to be fetch from the phone (locally).

Comment: How the data to fetch are stored ? Using a database ?

Comment: @dm_tr Using a database (Sqlite)

Comment: @GTG check the answer below

Comment: @dm_tr sorry it's my fault .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist, add the plugin [flutter_rounded_date_picker](https://pub.dev/packages?q=flutter_rounded_date_picker) and run `flutter pub get` command.
Import the package

`import 'package:flutter_rounded_date_picker/rounded_picker.dart';`
And try this

```
InkWell(
  child: Text("Pick Date"),
  onTap: () async {
    DateTime date = await showRoundedDatePicker(context: context,);
    if (null != date) {
      // Run you sqflite command here and pass it the selected date as parameter
    }
  },
),
```